# Finding equations of a cone that makes an angle pi/4 with positive zaxis

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

The question asks for equations in cylindrical and spherical coordinates, and parameterization for the cone.[This is my sketch for the cone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wt9i.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Thr quations of all such cones are $(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}=z^{2}$ for positive a,b. Can you convert this to cylindrical coordiantes?

Comment: I have plug in your equation in xyz coordinates in GeoGebra and it is a right cone with different points on xy plane as the apex, shouldn't it be a cone with the apex at the origin, and sort of rotated towards the xy plane?(I have upload the picture of what does it  look like in my point of view)

Comment: The important thing is to make an angle of pi/4 with the z-axis, right?

Comment: oh, so the angle is not measured from the z-axis to the cone's axis but z axis to the side of the cone?

Comment: Yes, i think it is.

Comment: I am not so sure about the transformation to cylindrical coordinates, would setting x-a =r cos(theta) and likewise for y will do just fine?

Comment: I think it would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for the equation of a cone with hight h along z axis and circular base with radius r on xy plane. The intersection of such a cone with xz and yz planes are:

$z=-\frac hr x +h$; $\frac hr=tan \frac{\pi}4=1\rightarrow r=h, and, z=-x+h $

$y=-\frac hr x +h\rightarrow z=-y+h$

Any point on the cone on any cross section by a plane parallel with xy plane is a circle with equation $x^2+y^2=R^2$ where R is is the radius of the circle. In a cone R varies from the tip to base of the cone and is a function of z. So to find the equation of the cone we must have:

$x=h-z$

$y=h-z$

$\rightarrow x^2+y^2=(h-z)^2$

If z=0, which means the intersection of cone with xy plane, then:

$x^2+y^2=h^2=r^2$

If $z=h$, which means the tip of the cone, then:

$x^2+y^2=0$